# How to check if all elements in one array exist in other array. However in the same order

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to solve the issue of searching through array1 to return a boolean if the elements of array1 can be found in array2. However, it can only be true if array2 contains array1 elements in *the same order*.

For example, `array1 = {3,4,5,6}` and `array2 = {3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 5, 6}` would be `true` since all elements are found in the same order.

Here's my code so far:

```
int size = Queue1.size();

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    arr3[i] = Queue1.dequeue();
}

boolean test = Arrays.asList(arr2).containsAll(Arrays.asList(arr3));
System.out.println(test);
```

The variable test returns to be `false` for the input of

- `arr3 = {3,4,5,6}`
- `arr2 = {3,4,2,1,5,10,9,8,6,7}`

Comment: You will have to write a bit of logic for this, the first step is to use a loop to find the first matching instance of the second list, then once you find it you use an inner loop to see if all preceding indexes match, if not then return to the outer loop and look for the next instance of the first index that matches, and repeat the process with the inner loop.

Comment: You haven't made an attempt, and this site is not a code writing service. Please show your attempt and describe how it didn't work. As a hint, loop through array1 keeping track of the index in array2 where you found a match for the element in array2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple algorithm to resolve your problem, base on `List<Integer>`  `contains` and `indexOf` functions:

code `(with comments)`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer[] array1 = new Integer[]{3,4,5,6};
    Integer[] array2 = new Integer[]{3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 5, 6};
    
    List<Integer> list1 =  Arrays.asList(array1);
    List<Integer> list2 =  Arrays.asList(array2);
    
    boolean check = false;
    int i = 0;
    for (Integer n : list1) {
        if (i == 0) {
            if (list2.contains(n)) {// first element check if it's on the second array
                check = true;
            }else check = false;
        }else {
            // check if the element in the array2 and its index is > of the previous element
            if (list2.contains(n) && list2.indexOf(n) > list2.indexOf(list1.get(i-1))) {
                check = true;
            }else {
                check = false;
                break;
                
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(check);
}
```

result:

```
input 1:

Integer[] array1 = new Integer[]{3,4,5,6};
Integer[] array2 = new Integer[]{3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 5, 6};

output 1: true

input 2:

Integer[] array1 = new Integer[]{3,7,4,6};
Integer[] array2 = new Integer[]{3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 5, 6};

output 2: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right approach, there's a suttle thing that you have to pay attention when using **Arrays.asList**, look:

If you pass an array of **int[]** to **asList()** it will return a **List<int[]>** rather than a **List of Integer**.

But if you pass an array of **Integer[]** to **asList()** it will return a **List of Integer** and you will be able to compare it.

See if on code it is more clear:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    Integer[] arr2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    boolean wrappers = checkWrappers(arr2, arr1);
    System.out.println(wrappers); // true

    int[] err1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] err2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    boolean primitives = checkPrimitives(err2, err1);
    System.out.println(primitives); // false
}

public static boolean checkWrappers(Integer[] outer, Integer[] inner) {
    List<Integer> integers2 = Arrays.asList(outer);
    List<Integer> integers1 = Arrays.asList(inner);
    return integers2.containsAll(integers1);
}

public static boolean checkPrimitives(int[] outer, int[] inner) {
    List<int[]> ints2 = Arrays.asList(outer);
    List<int[]> ints1 = Arrays.asList(inner);
    return ints2.containsAll(ints1); // compare object references not content
}
```

When passing **primitives** it compares the int[] **object** **reference** instead of comparing each element as you would want to.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple solutions.

The idea in both is to see, for each element x in the first list, whether it is in the second list. If it is, we focus on the remaining part of the list (subList).

The second method works, because indexOf returns -1 if the element was not found.

```java
private static boolean test(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
    int i = 0;
    for (int x : list1) {
        List<Integer> tempList = list2.subList(i, list2.size());
        if (tempList.contains(x)) {
            i = list2.indexOf(x);
        }
        else return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean test2(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int len = list2.size();
    
    for (int x : list1) {
        j = list2.subList(i, len).indexOf(x);
        if (j < 0) return false;
        i += j;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```